# Need to expand the size of /boot

Tags: boot, partitioning, upgrade, gparted, luks

I want to upgrade to the newest version of Ubuntu, but I keep getting the error "Not enough free disk space". The upgrade needs a total of 90.6M of free space.

My problem is that boot presently uses 51.6 MB of space and only has 5 MB left. I.e, the total size of boot is only 56.6 MB. The upgrade requires 90.6MB.

I have tried using gparted to resize the partition that boot is on, but I have a problem.

There's plenty of free room left on my hard drive at 435 GB free, 25 GB used.

I have 2 partitions. 1 is 255 MB, the other is 496 GB.

This is the warning message that appears in gparted
[image: Warning message]

When I click on resize/move for the main partition, the slider bar won't move.
[image: Screenshot from gparted]

I've also done the automated clean up, but it doesn't remove enough of the files to leave 90.6 MB free.

How can I expand the boot partition?

Comment: Try to use search.

Comment: @muru disagree - if their boot partition is only 58MB and the install needs 91MB, the partition needs resized.  Assuming they're using actual partitions

Comment: @ThomasW. ah, yes. I'll let the vote stand, since it's bound to be closed anyway.

Comment: @muru Indeed, just wanted to point out that point :)

Comment: Edit your post to include the output of `lsblk` and `sudo parted -l`.

Comment: You have an encrypted partition and may be a little more complicated resize a LUKS partition. Take a look here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions

Comment: related [How do I resize an encrypted LVM to install another copy of Ubuntu?](//askubuntu.com/a/262212)

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's not the answer to your question it might be the solution for your problem:

Your boot partition's size of 250 MB is big enough - at least if you don't want to use the last 10 kernels.

Open a terminal and use the command `ls -l /boot/vm*` to display the installed kernels:

```
% ls -l /boot/vm*
-rw------- 1 root root 5825376 Dez 18 01:42 /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-70-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 5825376 Dez 18 01:42 /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-74-generic
```

In this case there are two kernels which is fine. You should at least keep the previous version in case of problems. I think your list will be longer and you can use `apt-get autoremove` to remove the old kernels:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove linux-image-3.13.0-70-generic
```

If your `/boot/` partition was full because of old kernel versions you can remove most of them with this command and then proceed with your upgrade.

**Update**:
Look at [these solutions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot?lq=1), too